# How to write encoder for the conversion of avi to wmv format using C# or Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is anyone trying to write their encoder code for the conversion of avi to wmv format using C#.
I have tried most of the conversion like WMVEncoder or ffmpeg but I didn't get any success on the Silverlight project.

The silverlight project I am developing is an In-Browser application.The application consist of camera access which the recording is done & saved in raw format. I am able to convert the raw data format to *.AVI. Also I have the problem of accessing the "My Videos" folder in silverlight 4.0 for saving the converted *.AVI videos but in silverlight 5.0 beta I have solved that problem using below link:
[Silverlight 5 Trusted applications](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications.aspx)
So I am using silverlight 5.0 beta for now onwards.

> The WMVEncoder/ffmpeg cannot run on the C# silverlight application because it gives an
>
> interoperability exception (method access error)
>
> though we have trusted application settings.Also we were not able to compile the ffmpeg libraries in C#.
>
> So the idea behind writing is to develop our own encoder which can be able to run in the In-browser application using C# silverlight 5.0.

If anyone knows how to write there own encoders for *.AVI to *.WMV conversion.

Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: you want to transcode the file on the client? What purpose is that for?

Comment: We need to encode on client side so that we need not send the 600 MB file to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transcoding of media files should be done server side. [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75402be0-c603-4998-a79c-becdd197aa79&displaylang=en) has a complete .NET accessible [SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expressionencoder/archive/2009/07/29/9853000.aspx) you can use in C# that includes batch transcoding and it supports transcoding from AVI to WMV.